# How to mock Find() from EF via Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

My testable function uses `EF.Find()` so as I discovered I need to implement mock of find.

The only code which seems to get compiled is `c#`

```
testsContextMock.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<Type>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
.Returns<object[]>(hashes => testsMock.Object.FirstOrDefault(u => u.hash == (string)hashes[0]))
```

Where `testsContextMock` is `Mock<DbContext>` object, and `testsMock` is `Mock<DbSet<MyEntity>>`.

But after completion of this code I get this error

```
System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. 
Setup on method with 2 parameter(s) cannot invoke callback 
with different number of parameters (1).
```

As Im assume this is happening cause in testable method signature of calling `Find()` is `DbSet<MyEntity>.Find(params object[] keyValues)` and signature of mocked method is `DbContext.Find(Type entityType, params object[] keyValues)`. And if Im trying to mock other overload it somehow fails with compiler error
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object[]' to 'System.Type'`

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to mock something (especially related to EF) and it's not really easy to do then you may want to indirect the call. E.g. define an interface whose implementation will make calls to EF itself (an adapter), you can easily mock the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take closer look at signatures of called functions:

1. `DbContext.Find(Type entityType, params object[] keyValues)` what we get at mock
2. `DbSet<MyEntity>.Find(params object[] keyValues)` what we get at method

It's quite easy to see, but somehow I missed that first one reference *context* and second one *set*. So in my calling instead of *Find*-ing from context `m`

```
testsContextMock.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<Type>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
```

I just need to find from proper *DbSet*

```
testsContextMock.Setup(m => m.MyEntities.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
```